# GraphQL type 'Object'?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, express-graphql

I have a MongoDB mongoose schema like this:

```
const playerSchema = Schema({                    
    conditions: { type : Object },                 
    date: String    
})
```

With a collection like this:

```
{
 _id: 5cee935cb56d5f794b452d78,
 conditions:
 { 
    condition_a: [5.9, 6.0],
    condition_b: [6.1, 4.9],
    condition_c: [4.9, 4.0]
 },     
 date: 'Wed May 29 2019 16:45:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
},
{
 _id: 5cee935cb56d5f794b452d70,
 conditions:
 { 
    condition_a: [5.8, 6.1],        
    condition_c: [4.3, 3.0]
 },     
 date: 'Wed May 29 2019 16:47:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
},
[...]
```

How I can make GraphQL Schema for this?
I've tried something like this

```
buildSchema(`
 type Player {
    _id: ID!    
    condition: Object         
    date: String         
 }
`)
```

Also tried: `[[String]]` , `{}` , `{String}` ... with no lucky

Make a collection with conditions and relations to `Player` is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
type Condition {
    condition_a: [String],
    condition_b: [String],
    condition_c: [String],    
}

type Player {
    _id: ID!    
    condition: Condition         
    date: String         
 }
```